# Why does the Main have to be static to be able to accept command line arguments?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line-arguments

Do I have to have 2 different Main methods, 1 without any arguments and 1 with `string[] args` but private and static?

Comment: Can you post an example? I don't quite follow.

Comment: I don't understand the question.  Why would you not expect the method to have to be static?  (And why would you have two versions of the `Main` method -- if you want to accept arguments, declare a `string[]` parameter to contain them and that's the only version of the method you should have.)

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-AU/clr/thread/199b7536-501b-4c8b-9fcb-289b158e1be6

Comment: What confuses *me* is what whether a method is static or not has to do with its arguments.

Comment: Sorry guys I got confused with the MainWindow method that was not static.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No - you only have to have one `Main` method. Indeed, if you have more than one static `Main` method in a class, I don't believe you can specify that class as an entry point.

It *does* have to be static though; the class can't be generic and neither can the method. It can be:

- Any accessibility (as can the class)
- Void or have a return value of `int`
- Parameterless or have a parameter type of `string[]`

It has to be static and non-generic as otherwise the CLR would have to create an instance of the class or work out what type parameter you wanted, respectively. It doesn't have enough information to make either of those decisions - but it doesn't need any information for a static non-generic method in a non-generic class.

Answer (score 12):

> Why does `Main` have to be `static` <strike>to be able to accept command line arguments</strike>?

There, fixed that for you.

`Main` has to be static so that it can be called without an object instance.  This is necessary because `Main` is called before any instances are created.